# Finding linear function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, slope

The cost of production per unit is $\$1$. The sale price is $\$3$. The number of units I expect to sell in a week is $30$ units.

The question I am asked to answer is to find the equation in slope intercept form where $x$ represents price and $y$ represents the number of units sold.
I feel like the question is a bit vague, which is why I’m confused.

Comment: Yes this is vague because it does not specify what the equation should represent. Should it represent revenue? Should it represent profit? Are there fixed costs, or only variable costs ($1 per unit). I think this is a poorly stated problem.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense that you'd have a variable $x$ for price when you also know that the sale price is $\$ 3$, I think there's some information missing here. Are you sure $x$ isn't the revenue or profit? It'd still be measured in the same units (dollars), but would make more sense as a question.

Comment: Right that’s why I was confused, if it was asking for the total revenue it would make sense to me, but the way it’s stated is confusing. I’m also supposed to find the y-intercept and and slope which doesn’t make sense with the information I’ve been given. Thank you for your comments.